# why the regression doesnt work? (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, regression

I have a accelerometer signal as below:
[image]

and I have a walking signal as below:

[image]

I tried to regress these two signal using regression. Here is the code:

```
regMat=zeros(size(walkVec,1),size(walkVec,2));
for i=1:size(data,1)
   b=regress(walkAcc', walkVec(i,:)');
    regMat(i,:)=walkVec(i,:)-repmat(b,1,length(walkAcc));
    regData(i,:)=[data(i,1:(ipt(1)-1)),regMat(i,:), data(i, 
     (ipt(2)+1):size(data,2) ) ];
 end

 figure(1),hold on, plot(data(1,:),'r'), plot(regData(1,:)), title 
('regressed (b) and raw(r) ')
legend('raw','regressed')
 xlabel('samples')
ylabel('Intensity')
```

and here is the reslts:
[image]

as you can see the regression doesnt really work. Do you have any idea why and how I can fix it?

Thanks a lot and kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if regData has any data in the first column. This can also happen if one data is several magnitudes higher or lower. It becomes negligible in the same chart. I tried your code with dummy data and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is just a visual representation of regressions, and you don't need to store/process data, I suggest you to use the function `plotregression` (https://it.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/plotregression.html).